# Lazy load and play multiple random html5 videos in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, lazy-loading, random-access

I'm creating a webpage to play multiple html5 videos at the same time. I added the lazy load script + visible only script, so only the videos in the viewport will load and play when I scroll. Look at the demo.

Everything works fine. Each time I refresh the page, it will display the videos randomly. When I scroll down, it loads videos and plays, and when I keep scrolling down, the videos that go upward will pause. When I scroll up back to the videos I just watched, they will resume. It's expected.

But there is a problem. When I scroll down then scroll up, the videos above the viewport are starting to resume but the videos under the viewport do not pause but keep playing.

I don't know what to do to make the videos under the viewport stop playing. In the demo, it works maybe fine, but when I copy the same code and put it in a HTML file on my PC, so it displays only 3 videos in a row on my screen, the problem occurs: the videos under the viewport keeps playing when I scroll up.

Here is the demo - Please click to view full:

```js
var bLazy = new Blazy({
  // Options
});


// Shuffles elements in a list

var ul = document.querySelector("ul"), // get the list
  temp = ul.cloneNode(true), // clone the list
  i = temp.children.length + 1;

// shuffle the cloned list (better performance)
while (i-- > 0)
  temp.appendChild(temp.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);

ul.parentNode.replaceChild(temp, ul); // copy shuffled back to 'ul'



$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('video').each(function() {
    if ($(this).visible()) {
      $(this)[0].play();
    } else {
      $(this)[0].pause();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

*> :first-child,
*> :nth-child(2),
*> :nth-child(3) {
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 70px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blazy/1.8.2/blazy.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-visible/1.2.0/jquery.visible.min.js"></script>


<ul>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.webm" type="video/webm"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://iandevlin.com/html5/rwd-video/parrots.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.nlm.nih.gov/web/documentation/TemplateDocumentation/video_files/IN_Intro-800.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://dev.opera.com/articles/introduction-html5-video/videos/windowsill.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.iandevlin.com/html5test/webvtt/v/upc-tobymanley.theora.ogg" type="video/ogg"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="http://henriksjokvist.net/examples/html5-video/video.ogg" type="video/ogg"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.webm" type="video/webm"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://iandevlin.com/html5/rwd-video/parrots.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.nlm.nih.gov/web/documentation/TemplateDocumentation/video_files/IN_Intro-800.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://dev.opera.com/articles/introduction-html5-video/videos/windowsill.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.iandevlin.com/html5test/webvtt/v/upc-tobymanley.theora.ogg" type="video/ogg"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="http://henriksjokvist.net/examples/html5-video/video.ogg" type="video/ogg"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.webm" type="video/webm"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://iandevlin.com/html5/rwd-video/parrots.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.nlm.nih.gov/web/documentation/TemplateDocumentation/video_files/IN_Intro-800.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://dev.opera.com/articles/introduction-html5-video/videos/windowsill.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="https://www.iandevlin.com/html5test/webvtt/v/upc-tobymanley.theora.ogg" type="video/ogg"> </video></li>
<li><video class="b-lazy" width="628" height="352" loop autoplay> <source data-src="http://henriksjokvist.net/examples/html5-video/video.ogg" type="video/ogg"> </video></li>
</ul>
```